# HTMX & Django: Using HMTX across multiple Class Based Views

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

**Desired Outcome:**
I am attempting to implement a UX flow with htmx and Django, where the user first selects a date, then a timeslot (determined based on the date), then a ticket (availability calculated based on date and time) and then inputs any special requests. Forms and elements are dynamically rendered without page refresh up to this point. User can then proceed to the next step (booking summary) which is on a different page. At each stage (i.e. each post in my view) I am saving important variables in the session. These are the variables posted via htmx and will be used later to create a model instance.

**Problem**:
When I get to the final view, the post request returns a blank page and the url does not change. It also seems like it is initiating the post request from my original view once again (since the selected date variable is printed again in console as *None* whereas prior to this, it is the date selected from the SelectDateForm).

**Context:**

The project is for an activity booking website. This flow is how the user books a particular activity.

It works up until the final view in that flow (SpecialRequestsView), and I am able to update the forms with a dynamic response (for example, if I have rendered the SelectTicketForm, but decide go back to the SelectDateForm and change the date, a new set of timeslots are displayed, and the SelectTicketForm is once again hidden until a timeslot is selected).

Suspect I may need to completely redesign but cannot find much documentation / research on htmx across class based views in Django.

My views.py:

```py
class CreateBookingView(View):
    template_name = 'bookings/create_booking.html'
    form_class1 = SelectDateForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **Kwagrs):
        date_form = self.form_class1()
        listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context = {
            'date_form': date_form,
            'listing': listing,
            'slug': self.kwargs['slug']
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        is_htmx = request.headers.get('HX-Request') == True
        selected_date = request.POST.get('select_date')
        request.session['booking_date'] = selected_date
        print(f'Selected Date: {selected_date}')
        listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        try:    
            available_time_slots = calculate_availability(listing, selected_date)
        except:
            available_time_slots = None

        past_date_error = "You cannot select a past date."
        no_availability_error = "We're sorry. There is no availability for your selected date. Please select another date."

        # Store session Variables
        request.session['listing_slug'] = self.kwargs['slug']
        request.session['booking_date'] = selected_date

        if selected_date is not None:
            date_date = datetime.strptime(request.session['booking_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        else:
            date_date = date(2150, 12, 30)

        context = {
            'available_time_slots': available_time_slots,
            'slug': self.kwargs['slug'],
            'selected_date': selected_date,
            'selected_date_datetype': date_date,
            'today': date.today(),
            'past_date_error': past_date_error,
            'no_availability_error': no_availability_error
            }
        
        #if selected_date is not None:
        return render(request, 'bookings/timeslots.html', context)
            



            
        
class TimeSlotView(View):
    
    form_class = SelectTicketForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        slug = request.session['listing_slug']
        listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, slug=slug)
        selected_time_str = request.POST.get('data-timeslot')
        selected_time_str = selected_time_str.replace('datetime.time', '')
        booking_date = request.session['booking_date']
        selected_time_dict = eval(selected_time_str)

        start_time = get_start_time(selected_time_dict, booking_date)
        end_time = get_end_time(selected_time_dict, booking_date)

        # store session Variables
        request.session['selected_time_dict'] = selected_time_dict

        form = self.form_class(listing=listing, ticket_dict=selected_time_dict)

        context = {
            'slug': request.session['listing_slug'],
            'start_time': start_time,
            'end_time': end_time,
            'form': form,
        }

        #if start_time is not None and end_time is not None: # if it doesn't work might need to be start_date and end_time
        return render(request, 'bookings/book_tickets.html', context)
    

class BookTicketsView(View):
    form_class = SelectTicketForm
    special_req_form = SpecialRequestForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = request.session['listing_slug']
        special_req_form = self.special_req_form()
        selected_time_dict = request.session['selected_time_dict']
        
        selected_ticket_quantities = []
        for ticket in selected_time_dict['tickets']:
            selected_tickets = {}
            selected_tickets['ticket_id'] = ticket['ticket_id']
            selected_tickets['ticket_name'] = ticket['ticket_name']
            selected_tickets['selected_quantity'] = int(request.POST.get(f'ticket_{ticket["ticket_id"]}'))
            selected_ticket_quantities.append(selected_tickets)

        print(f'Selected Tickets {selected_ticket_quantities}')

        selected_ticket_list = [ticket for ticket in selected_ticket_quantities if ticket['selected_quantity'] != 0]

        print(f'Selected Tickets List {selected_ticket_list}')

        # store session variables
        request.session['selected_ticket_list'] = selected_ticket_list

        total_selected_quantity = sum(ticket['selected_quantity'] for ticket in selected_ticket_list)
        max_selection = selected_time_dict['total_availability']
        no_selection_error = "Please select at least one ticket to proceed."
        max_selection_error = f'Too many tickets selected. Maximum selection is: {int(max_selection)}'

        context = {
            'slug': slug,
            'special_req_form': special_req_form,
            'max_selection': int(selected_time_dict['total_availability']),
            'selected_ticket_list': selected_ticket_list,
            'total_selected_quantity': total_selected_quantity,
            'no_selection_error': no_selection_error,
            'max_selection_error': max_selection_error,
            'max_selection': max_selection
        }


        return render(request, 'bookings/special_requests.html', context)
    
    

class SpecialRequestsView(View):
    formclass = SpecialRequestForm
    template_name = 'bookings/special_requests.html'



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = request.session['listing_slug']
        special_requests = request.POST.get('special_req')
        if special_requests is not None:
            request.session['special_booking_request'] = special_requests
            print(special_requests)
        
        return redirect(reverse('bookings:booking_summary', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
        



class BookingSummaryView(View):
    template_name = 'bookings/booking_summary.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_time_dict = request.session['selected_time_dict']
        booking_date = request.session['booking_date']
        start_time = get_start_time(selected_time_dict=selected_time_dict, booking_date=booking_date)
        end_time = get_end_time(selected_time_dict=selected_time_dict, booking_date=booking_date)
        selected_ticket_list = request.session['selected_ticket_list']
        listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        try:
            special_requests = request.session['special_booking_request']
        except:
            special_requests = None
        
        context = {
            'start_time': start_time,
            'end_time': end_time,
            'selected_ticket_list': selected_ticket_list,
            'listing': listing,
            'special_requests': special_requests
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

My forms.py:

```py
class SelectDateForm(forms.Form):
    
    select_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'id': 'select_date'}))




class SelectTicketForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, listing, ticket_dict, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectTicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ticket_dict = ticket_dict
        tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(listing=listing)

        for ticket in tickets:
            self.fields[f'ticket_{ticket.uid}'] = TicketSelectField(
                ticket_id=ticket.uid,
                price=ticket.price,
                adults = ticket.adults,
                children = ticket.children,
                label=ticket.name,  # Display the ticket name as the label
                initial=0,  # Initial quantity set to 0
                min_value=0,  # Minimum value allowed,
                max_value = ticket_max_availability(ticket, ticket_dict),
                required=False,
                help_text=ticket.info,
                widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                })
            )
            print(f"Ticket {ticket.uid} - Price: {ticket.price}")


class SpecialRequestForm(forms.Form):
    
    special_req = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}), required=False)
```

create_booking.html:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="container" style="width: 80%">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-left">
                    <h1 style='font-family: copperplate mt; font-size: 80px'>{{ listing }}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div id="listingimagecarousel" class="carousel slide mb-5">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" style="height: 50%;">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            {% if listing.listing_image %}
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ listing.listing_image.url }}" alt="Listing Image" />
                            {% else %}
                                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="width: 80%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex;">
        <form hx-post='{% url "bookings:create_booking" slug=listing.slug %}' hx-target='#available-time-slots'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ date_form }}
            <input type="submit" value="View Time Slots" class="dayzeout-btn dayzeout-grdnt-outline-btn">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="available-time-slots">
        {% include 'bookings/timeslots.html' %}
    </div>


{% endblock %}

<script>
    $('#flexCheckDefault').prop('checked', true);
    $('#flexCheckDefault').prop('checked', false);
</script>
```

timeslots.html:

```html
{% block content %}
{% load custom_filters %}


<div class="container mt-5" style="width: 80%">
    <div id="time-slots">
        {% if selected_date != None %}
            {% if selected_date_datetype < today %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                    <i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i> {{ past_date_error }}
                </div>        
            {% else %}
                {% if available_time_slots == None %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                        <i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i> {{ no_availability_error }}
                    </div>
                {% else %}    
                    {% for timeslot in available_time_slots %}
                    <button name="timeslot_button" hx-post='{% url "bookings:select_timeslot" slug=slug %}' hx-target="#time-slots" hx-swap="outerHTML show:#ticket-form:top " class="select-time-slot btn dayzeout-green-btn mt-2" hx-include="this">
                        {{ timeslot.start_time|format_time }} - {{ timeslot.end_time|format_time }}
                        <input name="data-timeslot" value="{{timeslot}}" type="hidden">
                    </button>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>


</div>

{% endblock %}
```

book_tickets.html:

```html
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% load custom_filters %}

<style>
    .custom-tooltip {
        --bs-tooltip-bg: #c855fa;
        --bs-tooltip-color: var(--bs-white);
        --bs-tooltip-opacity: 1;
      }
</style>


<div class="container mt-5" style="width: 80%; text-align: center;">
    <row class="mb-5">
        <h6>Selected Time:</h6><button class="dayzeout-btn dayzeout-grdnt-nhvr-btn" disabled><strong> {{start_time|format_time}} - {{end_time|format_time}}</strong></button>
    </row>
    <div class="container  mt-5" style="width: 100%;" id="ticket-form">
        <form hx-post='{% url "bookings:book_tickets" slug=slug %}' hx-target="#special-requests" hx-swap="show:#special-requests:top">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
                <h3>Select Tickets:</h3>
                <table class="table" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th name="ticket & description" scope="col" hidden/>
                            <th name="price" scope="col" hidden/>
                            <th name="quantity" scope="col" hidden/>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for field in form %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>{{field.label}}</strong>
                                    <i class="bi bi-info-circle-fill" style="font-size: 15px; color: #000000" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip" data-bs-title="{{field.field.adults}} Adults; {{field.field.children}} Children"></i>   
                                    <br/>
                                    {{field.help_text}}
                                </td>
                                <td>£{{field.field.price}}</td>
                                <td>{{field}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm Selection" class="dayzeout-btn dayzeout-grdnt-btn">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="special-requests">
    
</div>

{% endblock %}

<script>
$(function () {
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

special_requests.html:

```html
{% block content %}


<div class="container mt-5" style="width: 80%; text-align: center;">
    <div id="ticket-selection">
        {% if total_selected_quantity == 0 %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                <i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i> {{ no_selection_error }}
            </div>
        {% elif total_selected_quantity > max_selection %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                <i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i> {{ max_selection_error }}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {% for ticket in selected_ticket_list %}
                <div class="col">
                    <strong>Your Selection</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ ticket.selected_quantity }} x {{ ticket.ticket_name }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="container mt-5" style="width: 80%">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <row class="row mb-2">
                            <strong>Special Requests:</strong>
                        </row>
                        <row class="row">
                            {{ special_req_form }}
                        </row>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Selection" class="dayzeout-btn dayzeout-grdnt-btn">
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

booking_summary.html (unfinished, shouldn't be causing issue):

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% load custom_filters %}

<div class="container mt-5" style="width: 80%; text-align: center;">
    <div>
        <h6>Your Tickets</h6>
        {{ selected_ticket_list }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <row class="row">
            <h6>Special Requests</h6>
        </row>
        <row class="row">
            {{ special_requests }}
        </row>
        <row class="row">
            <button class="dayzeout-btn dayzeout-grdnt-btn">Proceed to Payment</button>
        </row>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the issue well, but I think you're trying to use django's `redirect` while making request via htmx. This won't work, since htmx handles redirection by using response headers.

You should try adding [django-htmx](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx) to your project.

It includes a bunch of utils which are very helpful and saves you a lot of time when using django with htmx.

To solve your issue you need to replace

```
return redirect(reverse('bookings:booking_summary', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
```

with

```
return HttpResponseClientRedirect(reverse('bookings:booking_summary', kwargs={'slug': slug})
```

Ref:
https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#django_htmx.http.HttpResponseClientRedirect

Also when dealing with htmx I found FBVs to be much easier to work with then CBVs. There's a lot of magic involving CBV that might be quite tricky to override to get it to work with htmx.